# How to verify if an applet is already installed on a Java Card

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I'm writing a program that is able to upload an applet automacaly once the card is inserted into the reader.

I've done this part and i"d like to be able to verify if the applet is already installed on the card before trying to install it again.
I'm using the `javax.smartcardio` package

this what what i think i'm supposed to use in order to send the command :

```
            Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");
            CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
            ResponseAPDU resp = channel
                                .transmit(new CommandAPDU());
```

but i don't know how to send the command using may applet's AID.
My applet's AID is `01020304050607080900`

Comment: ,. be aware that you can only install/instanciate an applet with the same AID once. And the same for loading a package to the card. So the first thing you should do is to also check if the package containing the applet is already uploaded in the card.

Comment: @jlanza Thanks, but how should i do it usiqng the package java.smartcardio ?

Comment: @salomon_diei from the comments to the answer below, you are using GlobalPlatformPro. If you upload a package that is already loaded, you will get an error. So you have to do it, either implementing the whole uploading process with java.smartcario, or with GPPro libraries or parsing GPPro output. Besides you can always list the content stored in the card and see if a matching AID is install (package, applet and instance)

Comment: @jlanza How can i implement and use the GPPro libraries in my code ? I'm new to java so i don't know how to use an external libary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each applet has an unique AID (application identifier). You could list all installed applications using the GlobalPlatform GET STATUS command, but the easiest way is to execute just a SELECT command. If the applet is installed the SELECT command will return a response ending with 9000 as status word. 6a82 means "file not found" - this indicates the file is not found, i.e. the applet is not installed.

The command is:

```
00A40404 <AID length> <your AID>
```

```java
byte[] aid = {(byte)0x01, (byte)0x02, (byte)0x03, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x05, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x07, (byte)0x08, (byte)0x09, (byte)0x00};
ResponseAPDU resp = channel
                                .transmit(new new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, aid, 0xFF));
if (resp.sw == 0x9000) {
// applet is already installed
}
```

Take note, that if the applet installation has failed, only the package will be installed, the applet will not have instantiated and cannot be detected this way, but I assume you already have handled this during the installation process.

Another alternative is just to let the installation happen, usually the error reported during the installation process would be 0x6A89, meaning "file already exists".

Comment: Can you please show me how to implement it ? I updated my question

Comment: i implemented the code, and the response status SW that i get using the method getSw() is always 27270 instead of 9000 when the applet is installed and 6A89 when the applet is already installed

Comment: In order to install the applet on the card, i'm using gp.exe. Is there a means to install it directly in my java code ?

Comment: GPPro also offers a library, I guess, which can be used directly in your code.

Comment: I changed the P2 parameter to 0. Your card seems not to support this parameter.

Comment: I tried with the parameter P2 set to 0 and i get a response status SW = 27266 for both cases

Comment: Thanks for the info, but could you help me implement the libary into my code ?

Comment: When i use the toString() method on the respose, i get the following message : ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6a82

Comment: 6a82 means "file not found" - this indicates the file is not found, i.e. the applet is not installed.

Comment: The problem is that it displays the same message when i install the applet on the card and when i delete it. I use gp.exe to install, delete and verify that the applet is well installed on the card.

Comment: It is really strange what you are experiencing with your SELECT command. Try to delete the applet and the SW should be 6a82 or similar, install it and the result must be 9000. Otherwise the card is questionable.

Comment: I deleted it and reinstalled it, and the result showed was 9000. The problem was that iwas loading the applet on the card, but not installong it. Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: Great that it works, if the problem that an applet was not completely installed must also be covered but simply advice would not work. Then a direct interaction with the GPPro library is needed querying the installed packages and applications with a GET STATUS command. Consult the [library implementation](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/tree/master/library) then.